# Automatically upload Maven compiled jar to FTP location?

Tags: java, maven, ftp

I have a Java project that uses Maven and I work in IntelliJ.

My current work process to test the code on my testing server is:

1. Run `install` from the Maven window

[image]

2. Using WinSCP to upload the compiled jar to the testing server.

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a custom task, like `install and upload` to the Maven toolbar in IntelliJ that executes `install` and then executes some code to upload the compiled jar via FTP.

Comment: It took me literally 30 sec to search in google how to upload jar through FTP using Maven. What is the problem with the solutions you can find in there?

Comment: Ironically searching that now yields this question as the first result for me.

Answer (score 1):

The steps are pretty simple.

In your POM, inside the  tag you can add:

```xml
    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>Whatever_ID</id>
            <url>ftp://your.ftp.url</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

If you need a username and a password, you can add them in your /.m2/settings.xml:

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
   <server>
      <id>Whatever_ID</id>
      <username>YourUsername</username>
      <password>YourPassword</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Then you can deploy using : `mvn deploy`

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and mark as solution when I've tested it. What happens to previously deployed JARs on the FTP server when a new one is deployed (if the jar name/version changes)? Do they stay or automatically get removed?

Comment: It depends if you use the version tag in maven. If you use it and you change the version tag, a new jar will be created.